# Borland C++ Builder 6 указатель на массив целых числе(Integer), почему не определяется длина и можно использовать элементы за выделенной областью?

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, int, borland-c++

ниже приведён код и результаты его выполнения.

```
int *k = new int[10];
for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {k[i] = i;}//Для демонстрации примера этого можно и не делать
k[115] = 555;
for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
  k[i] = i;
}
Memo1->Lines->Add(sizeof(*k));//возвращает 4
Memo1->Lines->Add(sizeof(*k));//возвращает 4
Memo1->Lines->Add(k[115]);//возвращает 555
```

Как определить количество элементов в массиве и/или под сколько элементов было выделено памяти.
Почему при явном объявлении количества элементов массива допустимо использовать элементы с ключами значения которых превышают выделенный диапазон?

P.S. вопрос почему бы не использовать более современный компилятор мне уже задавали. Для реализации запланированного в среде Borland C++ Builder 6 мне почти достаточно знаний, работаю я с другим языком, как раз продую разобраться как работает компилятор и осуществлялась работа с памятью в ранних C++, давно планировал начать программировать на C++(а вернее продолжить после не большого опыта в университете).

Comment: В данном случае вопрос не в Borland'е, а в стандарте еще С. В С++ просто используйте не голые указатели, а классы типа `vector` или `array`. Ну не влазит в один указатель еще и размер массива, на который он указывает (да это и не нужно, как и постоянные, при каждом обращении, проверки, нет ли выхода за пределы массива). В конце концов, кто тут программист — вы или компилятор? :)

Comment: *"Почему при явном объявлении количества элементов массива допустимо использовать элементы с ключами значения которых превышают выделенный диапазон?"* - это не допустимо. Причем ответственность за то, что это не произойдет, лежит на программисте. Это называется "выстрелить себе в ногу". Статья по теме: [неопределенное поведение может вызывать путешествия во времени](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)

Comment: В тему новых компиляторов: появилась такая штука, [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer), которая кроме прочего проверяет выход за границы массивов. Слишком медленная, чтобы использовать в релизных билдах, но полезная для отладки.